# What is ".v8flags.3.14.5.9.{Name}"?

Tags: node.js

I am doing a clean install of Windows 10 Professional (x64) and am noticing some peculiar files appearing in the root of my home directory, specifically I see...

`.v8flags.3.14.5.9.Ciel`

Ciel is obviously my username; I've tried to do a search on this file and found very little - the best I can tell is that it relates to `nodejs`, which might make sense because I have `Visual Studio 2015` installed.

Can anyone else identify what this file is, and if I need to keep it?

Comment: [V8](https://developers.google.com/v8/) is the Googles Javascript Engine and that file of yours can be related to either Google Chrome (as in the web browser) or Node.js (since Node runs on V8). As for the rest of the filename, `flags` are usually referenced to enabling `experimental` features.

Comment: the file is used by this node.js module: https://github.com/js-cli/js-v8flags/blob/master/index.js#L11

Comment: Thank you, guys. Is it safe to remove or hide? Or do I need to leave it alone?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can safely delete it.

The file is used by the `nodejs` module `v8flags` for caching. If you delete it it will create a new one on next run.

I guess it was created because `Gulp` depends on `v8flags` and:

> The ASP.NET 5 templates included in Visual Studio 2015 use Gulp, and they install Gulp into your project’s node_components folder so it’s all ready for you to use in your project.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt595751.aspx

Update: The new name of the file is `.v8flags.{version}.{md5-hash-of-username}.json`.

Comment: `vi8flags` also seems to be used by slack and spotify in inux